# Update list of users after a new one is created or deleted

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a very simple list of users and a User component.
all the update and delete logic is inside the User component. at this point I´m not sure if this is the best approach because if the user is deleted I need to communicate that back to the list of users

```
const Admin = () => {

    const [users, serUsers] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
        setUsers(usersFromtheDatabase())
    }, [])

    return users.map(user => <User user={user} />)

}

const User = (props) => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState(props.user)

    const deleteUser = () => {
        //logic here to delete the record from the database
    }

    return (
         <div>
             <p>{user.name}</p>
             <button onClick={() => deleteUser()}>delete</button>
         </div>
    )
}
```

should I move the update, edit logic to the main component or what would be the right way to keep the users list in sync? I thought about sending the entire list of users to each Use component

```
users.map(user => <User user={user} users={users} />)
```

but that will be expensive If have a big list of users right? What´s the recommended approach? thank you

Comment: You can use `redux` to maintain the state throughout the app. https://redux.js.org/

Answer (score 1):

Best way to implement is to move the delete functionality to Admin component which holds the users. Once deleted, just update the state(users) which will cause re-render.

Also, in the child component(User), you don't need to maintain a state for `user` as it is already derived from the parent via props.

```js
const Admin = () => {

    const [users, serUsers] = useState();

    const deleteUser = (user) => {
        // logic here to delete the record from the database
        // user.deleteFromDatabase();
        const updatedUsers = users.filter(u => user.id !== u.id)
        setUsers(updatedUsers);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        setUsers(usersFromtheDatabase())
    }, [])

    return users.map(user => <User user={user} deleteUser={deleteUser}/>)

}

const User = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <p>{props.user.name}</p>
            <button onClick={() => props.deleteUser(props.user)}>delete</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```